# Navigation bar disappears after navigating - HTML

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, navigationbar

I'm currently developing an asp.net core web app, and I'm struggling on correctly navigating through the app.

Here is my directory structure, note that I'm using Areas.

[image: 1st part]
[image: 2nd part]

Now, the exact problem is that I'm able to navigate through the pages that are in the main folder like Index, Index1 and Private, but once I go to the Area, I am no longer able tonavigate correctly.

It is remarkable to say that the Layout code of the _Layout and _LaunchLayout is almost the same, only changes the name of the navigation items and their destinations.

Once I click any item on the navigation bar to navigate, the corresponding page shows up but the navigation bar disappears.

I'd appreciate some help on this, thanks to you all beforehand.

---

### EDIT: Link to the project

https://github.com/Rogeraj2001/GraphicProofOfConcept.git

Comment: Could you provide your whole project for us to test it? Just structure is difficult to find the solution.

Comment: Yes , sorry @XinranShen . Now I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after trying some things I found a workaround. That has been to specify the view route in the controller action:

```
public IActionResult _ViewStart() {
    return View("~/Areas/LaunchArea/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`_ViewStart.cshtml` file should be in root view folder `Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`  not the `Views/Shared` folder, So move your `_ViewStart.cshtml` file out of shared folder:

[image]

Then modify the code to

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/LaunchArea/Views/Shared/_LaunchLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Now the area can load layout page successfully.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Roger Almirall Jou, Have you solved this issue now?

Comment: Hi @Xinran Shen , thanks for your suggestion. This change did not resolve my issue, since the reason for the `_LaunchLayout.cshtml` to be there was that if not I get this error:
`
InvalidOperationException: The view '_ViewStart' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Areas/LaunchArea/Views/Home/_ViewStart.cshtml /Areas/LaunchArea/Views/Shared/_ViewStart.cshtml /Views/Shared/_ViewStart.cshtml
`

Comment: However, if I navigate directly with the route to that page, I get the same as your picture.

Comment: I'm glad for your help, but I found a quite clean workaround, I'll post an answer myself.